# How do you call a programmer-defined function in javascript in an android webview?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, highcharts, android-webview

I have put a highchart gauge in an html file and am loading it into a webview. I made a function called set_needle() that sets the needle to a certain value. But when I try to load the javascript call to that function in Java, nothing happens. I have looked at several examples and they seem to me to be doing exactly what I am, so I am not sure what the problem is.

Here is the html/js:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var needle_value = 0;

function set_value(new_val) {
    needle_value = new_val;
    console.log("setting needle");
}

$(function () {

$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Activity Index - Last 24 Hour'
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: -125,
        endAngle: 125,
        background: [{
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#FFF'],
                    [1, '#333']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '109%'
        }, {
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#333'],
                    [1, '#FFF']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 1,
            outerRadius: '107%'
        }, {
            // default background
        }, {
            backgroundColor: '#DDD',
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '105%',
            innerRadius: '103%'
        }]
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200,

        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        minorTickWidth: 1,
        minorTickLength: 0,
        minorTickPosition: 'inside',
        minorTickColor: '#666',

        tickPixelInterval: 40,
        tickWidth: 1,
        tickPosition: 'inside',
        tickLength: 14,
        tickColor: '#666',
        tickAmount: 11,

        labels: {
            step: 5,
            rotation: 'auto',
            format: '{value}%'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Activity<br />Index',
            style: {'fontSize':'11px'},
            y: 5
        },
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 60,
            color: '#DF5353' // red
        }, {
            from: 60,
            to: 80,
            color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
        }, {
            from: 80,
            to: 120,
            color: '#55BF3B' // green
        },
        {
            from: 120,
            to: 140,
            color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
        },
        {
            from: 140,
            to: 200,
            color: '#DF5353' // red
        }]
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Activity Index',
        data: [20],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '% of daily average'
        }
    }]

},
// Add some life
function (chart) {
    if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
        setInterval(function () {
            var point = chart.series[0].points[0];

            point.update(needle_value);

        }, 3000);
    }
});
});
</script>
```

And here is the relevant java code:

```
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/SleepActivity.html");
    myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:set_value(50)");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are calling the JavaScript function immediately after the html page load url instruction, It could be possible that the page is not completely loaded when trying to execute JavaScript, resulting in an error.

If It is the case I suggest to postpone the `myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:set_value(50)");` instruction on the onPageFinished callback of a custom WebViewClient. Something like:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:set_value(50)");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample interface:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Hook it up to WebView like this:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

`Android` is the name of the javascript object, so you can call it from javascript like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

The `@JavascriptInterface` annotation is important; if you don't have it, the method can't be called from javascript.